# if pwdLastSet set to 0, user can't login

Tags: java, active-directory, weblogic

I am creating users in Active Directory using Java code.
I am using this AD in my authentication provider in WebLogic server.

I've googled a bit but didn't find satisfactory solution to this issue - my requirement is typical: user must change password after first logon.

I know there is an attribute called pwdLastSet for this purpose, however the issue is, if I set it to 0 at the time of user creation, this user is not able to login.

That's how I am setting it to 0:

```
mods[2] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("pwdLastSet", Integer.toString(0)));
```

Just in case if anyone would like to know what's value of userAccountControl:
For userAccountControl, I am doing following:

```
attrs.put("userAccountControl", Integer.toString(LDAPConstants.UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + LDAPConstants.UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE));
```

After disabled user is created, I set password and enable it:

```
mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl",Integer.toString(LDAPConstants.UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT)));
```

Help?

Thanks.

Comment: If I don't set pwdLastSet value, it's set to some value (probably current timestamp) and user is able to login, now using LDAP browser tool, if I set it to 0, user can't login.

Comment: It sounds like you may have something out of order... after you run set password and enable the account are you once again setting pwdLastSet to 0?

Comment: Please provide the error message the user gets when he/she attempts to log in. Also, if you have access to your domain controller(s), I suggest you take a look at security events in the Event Log, there might be further info to help troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp - No, I am modifying all these things together: setting password, enabling account and setting pwdLastSet.

Comment: I get only following in audit log which doesn't give any clue as such: #### Audit Record Begin <04-Sep-2013 15:20:24>  <Severity =FAILURE>  <<<Event Type = Authentication Audit Event><ABC11@email.com><AUTHENTICATE>>>  <FailureException =javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090304]Authentication Failed: User ABC11@email.com javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090302]Authentication Failed: User ABC11@email.com denied> Audit Record End ####

Comment: It seems to me WebLogic Active Directory authenticator provider doesn't authenticate user if pwdLastSet is set to 0.

Comment: I did check Security logs in Event Viewer but couldn't find much for unsuccessful login attempt.